# Working with different views from large table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big large table and I want to have 3 different view from this table with a big where clause every time.

The problem of view is that it need execute the where clause every time I query it.

So, I Wonder about the best performant way to do this :

I am thinking about making 3 flag columns with case when statement when loading the large master table. Or loading 3 physical tables (aplying the big where on the etl)

Comment: Please show table structure, example data, and queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Function (filter1, filter2,.. ) with Returs @t Table

Comment: Hello, You mean, I load all data on the master table (without any where filter), then I use a table valued function with a filter as string parameters ?

Would this be performant ? because I need to query the filtered tables many times in some reports. 
thanks

Comment: then you use View - it's take all data from you large query and then fitlering - it's to long...

Comment: if you use function - you filtered data set in query inside this func and then returning clear data

Comment: You can create materilezed View  (may be 3 for each clause) for use it in query and refresh it every (5 minuts if data is offen update)

Comment: If I use function...it does not need to take data and filter them, every time I call it ? Does the result is precalculated ?

Comment: need take every time... So i recomendate you use "materialized view" - it precalculated + create some indexes for this view/ But don't forget update this View

Comment: I never used materialized view on SQL server...For now I didn't define a primary key on the master table, but I will use an incremental int key to build the indexed view (materialized view).
For update...data are daily refreshed...are the materialized view not automatically refreshed ?

Comment: for oracle - autorefresh. For MS SQL, Postgresql - need update manual. in MySQL not exists Materialized view - use table [http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views]